# need to copy sorted excel data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel with data on it. There are some cells which are empty. I am using the following code to sort the data to show only rows with data filled in it.

Issue is when I try to copy paste the data on to another sheet the sorted / hidden rows also get copied and pasted. Any way I can prevent it?

```
Sub cleanup2()
    BeginRow = 8
    EndRow = 1220
    ChkCol = 52

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 31 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Comment: Only copy those cells with data in them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get only visible cells.

For Example:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

copies only the visible cells of column A.